# Query In Linq using joins

Tags: linq

I have a query from sql but I can't seem to make it work in linq here is the query from sql server:

```
SELECT     MembersBU.MemberID, MembersBU.MemberFirst, MembersBU.MemberLast,
           MembersBU.MemberEmail, MembersBU.ValidEmail, 
                  MembersBU.EmailCap
FROM         groupMembers INNER JOIN
                  MembersBU ON groupMembers.MemID = MembersBU.MemberID
WHERE     (groupMembers.groupID = 3) AND (MembersBU.EmailCap = 1)
```

and here is the linq query:

```
 var query = from M in MembersBUs
 join GM in GroupMembers on M.MemberID equals GM.MemID
 where (GM.GroupID = 3) & (M.EmailCap = 1)
 select new {M.MemberID, M.MemberFirst, M.MemberLast, 
             M.MemberEmail, M.ValidEmail, M.EmailCap};
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use sql style where clause! You must use the language style. It looks like c# - you need to use == instead:

```
 var query = from M in MembersBUs
 join GM in GroupMembers on M.MemberID equals GM.MemID
 where (GM.GroupID == 3) && (M.EmailCap == 1)
 select new {M.MemberID, M.MemberFirst, M.MemberLast, 
             M.MemberEmail, M.ValidEmail, M.EmailCap};
```

And && instead of &.

It might be easier to use this query - because it's not an anonymous type:

```
IQueryable<MembersBU> = from M in MembersBUs 
     where (M.GroupMember.GroupID == 3) && (M.EmailCap == 1) 
     select M;
```

Comment: Oh yes that did it. I know I should start think in c# :) Thank you so much I almost started to pull my hair.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `&&` instead of `&` and `==` instead of `=`. Otherwise, your Linq query seems OK to me...

Comment: it throws me an error here it is: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int?'

Comment: I just updated my answer, you also need to change the '=' into '=='

Comment: I didn't even pay attention to "==" that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from M in MembersBUs 
join GM in GroupMembers on M.MemberID equals GM.MemID 
where (GM.GroupID == 3) && (M.EmailCap == 1) 
select new {M.MemberID, M.MemberFirst, M.MemberLast,  
         M.MemberEmail, M.ValidEmail, M.EmailCap};
```

The `where` clause uses normal C# syntax, == for equality and && of logical AND

Also, if you have the proper foreign-key relationship set up for the tables, you don't need to explcited state the join.  Linq will infer it automatically:

```
var query = from M in MembersBUs 
where (M.GroupMember.GroupID == 3) && (M.EmailCap == 1) 
select new {M.MemberID, M.MemberFirst, M.MemberLast,  
         M.MemberEmail, M.ValidEmail, M.EmailCap};
```